# Using cardView to set dynamic view

Tags: java, android, listview, android-cardview

How do i set the cardview to set image height to full if the image is one and to to divide the width to 2 if the image is 3, divide the width to 3 if the image is 3 and to divide into 4 if the image is more than 4 or equal 4 like in the image below.

If no image it should set the that image space to text. Just like the https://i.stack.imgur.com/KUK1H.jpg

Comment: **1.** you would probably need to calculate the screen width of the device, then while loading data, you'd set widths. **2.** Or you could simplify by using different "view types" of your `ListView` or `RecyclerView` and use "weights".